How to set RTL format using Zend_Pdf?
I want to display text in RTL format in my pdf,
I had tried setTextDirection but is does not available in Zend library ,
Is Zend_Pdf support the RTL format or not ?
or is there any other library available for RTL format?
can anyone help me about this ?

The GitHub page states: "This package is no longer maintained. We recommend TCPDF as a replacement." Anyway, I couldn't find any RTL methods in ZendPdf, but TCPDF has a setRTL() method.
